# What is the grammatical structure of this excerpt from Perdition in Our World?

Tags: grammar

> I, unknown to anyone, ***revealed every side of my flesh, charcoaled in
>   the pit of the mortality. Therein lies the ultimate contradiction of
>   human Spirit; it not having been in the slightest beyond the human
>   agency that the destructive nature of our confined bivouac of
>   temporality was created***. Maugre this, it is what we accept, nolens
>   volens: the choice eludes us, much to our grief. (From *Perdition in
>   Our World*)

The context is that humans are trapped in this horrible world of our own making; we have no choice whether to be part of it or not.

The grammar is so convoluted.

This "I" is someone who has struggled in this world and is now burnt, scarred, and unclothing himself without being seen by anyone.

I think it means this, but it is grammatically difficult.

Comment: This is bad writing: the author is more concerned with sounding impressive than with expressing his meaning (assuming he has one). If an author will not do you the courtesy of making his meaning clear, why should you do his work for him? Close the book and read something else.

Comment: I don't think so: *therein* has no evident referent, and what follows the semicolon appears to be an absolute gerund clause. But this is too incoherent to analyze. What is the source?

Comment: An [absolute construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction) is a subordinate phrase or clause which does not modify a particular constituent of its head clause but modifies or contextualizes the entire clause. It cannot stand on its own as an independent clause, so it is ungrammatical to join it to another clause with a semicolon.

Comment: I don't know what this work is, but it's not a good sign that [Google hasn't heard of it](https://www.google.com/search?q="Perdition+in+Our+World").

Comment: It means, approximately, "Life's a bitch and then you die"!

Answer (score 2):

What is the grammatical structure? It's mangled beyond recognition.

Assuming this isn't actually from the 18th century, it's a fake archaic speech. Maybe it's meant to sound intelligent, maybe it's meant to sound full of emotion, but the overall effect to me is just pretentious.

Additionally I wasn't able to find more information on the source, so I can't get more context. (This question is the only hit on Google for the phrase "bivouac of temporality"... not a good sign.)

That said, I'll try to gloss it for you without context:

> I, unknown to anyone, revealed every side of my flesh, charcoaled in the pit of the mortality.

Base sentence: "I revealed every side of my flesh." (i.e. I took off my clothes). "Unknown to anyone" is modifying "I" (I took off my clothes and no one saw). "Charcoaled in the pit of mortality" could be modifying "flesh" or "I"--it isn't specific without context. But unless the speaker's skin is literally burnt and blackened, it's probably a metaphor that describes the speaker's state of mind. He is aware of mortality, of his own certain death, and that makes him feel like he's trapped in a fiery pit. (I'm assuming that the "the" in "the mortality" is a typo; it shouldn't be there unless the speaker is referring to some specific mortality.)

> Therein lies the ultimate contradiction of human Spirit;

This structure is not too unusual, but it is very unusual to use a semicolon to join this sentence and the next. You might see that in material written in the 1700s-mid 1800s, but it is not currently considered good punctuation and you should not emulate it.
It would also have been better to say "Herein" instead of "Therein" because 'the ultimate contradiction of the human spirit' is defined immediately after the sentence, not before it.

> it not having been in the slightest beyond the human agency that the destructive nature of our confined bivouac of temporality was created.

This is honestly somewhat indecipherable. I also assume that the "the" in "the human agency" is a typo.

Then:

> our confined bivouac of temporality

Bivouac = an army camp. Temporality = worldliness (as opposed to transcendent spirituality), or being stuck in a specific, finite time. So "our too-small temporary home in a brief time period", thus "our brief lives".

> the destructive nature of our confined bivouac of temporality

The fact that our lives are limited is destructive. (It doesn't specify what is destroyed, probably something vague like 'the human spirit')

> it not being in the slightest beyond human agency that [x] was created

Emphatically states that [x] was created by human agency, not by some higher power or natural fact.

So overall, I would interpret the complete sentence to mean something along the lines of: 'We are able to recognize that we are trapped in a brief life which is certain to end; recognizing that fact makes it destructive; and the worst part is, it's entirely our human natures that let us understand it and suffer from it. This is the ultimate contradiction of the human spirit.'
But that is a guess. As I said, this is so pretentious as to be indecipherable, particularly without further context.

> Maugre this, it is what we accept, nolens volens: the choice eludes us, much to our grief." (From Perdition in Our World)

Maugre = in spite of
nolens volens = "whether or not we will it", i.e. regardless of whether we agree.
So, "Nevertheless, we accept [mortality], like it or not: we don't have a choice, much to our grief."

StoneyB is right. There's far too many good books out there to bother with this one.

Comment: +1 for tackling this train wreck. A very clear &  educational explanation. I've never heard "nolens volens" or "maugre," so there's that...